# how to make the list limit to 4 cards and it will load when scrolling in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

here's the code:
***HTML***

```
 <nz-content class="landing-content align-items-center">
    <section class="landing-body align-items-center w-100" nz-row nzType="flex">
      <div class="w-100" nzType="flex">
        <div class="app-section h-100 py-2" *ngFor="let data of tempThermometer; let i = index">
          <div class="app-section-item">
            <div class="section-content w-100 align-items-center">
              <div class="section-title w-100">
                <label [textContent]="data.title"></label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-subContent">
             <label [textContent]="data.content"></label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </nz-content>
```

***TS***

```
    tempThermometer = [{
    title: 'Header1',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },{
    title: 'Header2',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },{
    title: 'Header3',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },{
    title: 'Header4',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },{
    title: 'Header5',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },{
    title: 'Header6',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  },{
    title: 'Header7',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.'
  }]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to limit the data to 4 and every scroll it will load another 4 cards.

I have an api which is the `/api/room` and there's other way to limit `/api/room?start=1&length=4`.

But what I'm trying to do is every scroll it should have a loader and load another 4 data.

you can check the sample output here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgr1nk?file=src/styles.css

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#creating-items-in-the-viewport

You can user angular materil CDK virtual scrolling to achieve this beahviour

Comment: @SumitVekariya can you provide a sample?